# Does Cognitive service Speech SDK work in non ubuntu linux? If so, what are the required dependency?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-api

As subject, I tried to follow the quick start quide to run the speech api in non-ubuntu linux (see below), but I wonder if anyone get it to work or it is just not supported

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.77-70.82.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-64003) (gcc version 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2) (GCC)) #1 SMP Mon Dec 3 20:01:27 UTC 2018
```

but I got exception as the following.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.carbon_javaJNI.swig_module_init()V
at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.carbon_javaJNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.internal.carbon_javaJNI.<clinit>(carbon_javaJNI.java:517)
at com.microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.SpeechConfig.<clinit>(SpeechConfig.java:69)
```

Similiar thing happened in Ubuntu linux at first, but it is resolved after I installed libasound2 as recommended in the microsoft documentation.

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2
```

This leads me to think maybe I miss some of the dependencies but I cannot figure out what exactly I missed from the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, non-Ubuntu distributions are currently not supported / working.
The openssl library is an additional dependency; on Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 installed as the "libssl1.0.0" package, which ties it to a specific openssl version and library name.